# Doctrine QueryBuilder complex non-table query with subqueries

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have an SQL query I want to build with symfony/Doctrine2 QueryBuilder.

```
select     
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT sender)       
    FROM transactions) as senders,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT receiver) 
    FROM transactions) as receivers, 
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT message_type) 
    FROM transactions) as types
```

As seen in the description above, the main-query doesn't have a table

Is there a way to implement this in Querybuilder without writing the SQL Command as it is shown?

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> The same way you build a normal Query, you build a QueryBuilder object, just providing the correct method name. Here is an example how to build a QueryBuilder object:

```
//$em instanceof EntityManager
// example1: creating a QueryBuilder instance
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();`
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#constructing-a-new-querybuilder-object

But this will require your root query to map against an entity. Also the querybuilder doesn't provide any real support for subqueries, but there are some examples on how to achieve is anyway:

```
// build root query
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('Movie m')
  ->where('name = ?', 'Prometheus')
;

// build subquery
$subquery = $query->createSubquery()
  ->from('SeenMovie sm')
  ->where('m.name = sm.name')
;

// nest subquery and execute
$query->where('EXISTS (' . $subquery->getDql() . ')')->execute();
```

Borrowed from: https://www.philipphoffmann.de/2012/08/29/a-bulletproof-pattern-for-creating-doctrine-subqueries-of-any-complexity/